# Is there a way to lock an element to the left and right edge of it's container so it stretches to fill that container?

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to lock an elements position to the left and right edge of it's container so it stretches to fill that container?

I've been setting the left and right CSS properties like so but it doesn't work:

```
#Button1199  {
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
  right:20px;
}
```

Here is what I get:

[image]

Here is what I want:

[image]

Here is what I have so far:

```css
body {
 -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
 font-family:Verdana;
 font-weight:normal;
 font-size:12px;
}

#BorderContainer2085  {
 position:absolute;
 top:30px;
 left:37px;
 width:240px;
 height:160px;
 display:inline-block;
 border-width:1px;
 border-color:#696969;
 border-style:solid;
 border-radius:0px;
}

#Button1199  {
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:20px;
  right:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="BorderContainer2085">
 <input id="Button1199" type="button" value="Button">
</div >
```

In other words, is there a way to specify both left and right properties and have the element "stretch" well not stretch but resize. This type of layout feature is seen in other platforms, I'm wondering if it's available on the web.

Comment: I think you want to set the width of the button to 100% and display to block

Comment: @Kris This will work, but absolute elements will still take on the full width of the parent and push the button past the parent boundaries. A calculation should be done to negate the left and right values from the 100% width.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, but absolute elements will take on the full TOTAL width of it's container. So you'll have to do a calculation to determine the size.

```
#Button1199  {
   position:absolute;
   top:20px;
   left:20px;
   right:20px;
   width: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the `width` of the button to whatever you would like. In the example below I made it `80%` and `left,right` values to 0. Add `margin: 0 auto;` to center.

```css
body {
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-family: Verdana;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#BorderContainer2085 {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 240px;
  height: 160px;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #696969;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 0px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 30px;
  left: 37px;
}

#Button1199 {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="BorderContainer2085">
  <input id="Button1199" type="button" value="Button">
</div>
```

Comment: This works when the position of the left or right edge of element is irrelevant and it may be fine for some projects but if I would like to align the left and right edge to other elements anchored to a specific position along the sides of the container the left and right positions of the element will move if the container is resized.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
Width:100%;
```

To the button

And set margin if required

Comment: If the position is not zero this causes the element to extend over the edge of it's container.